# CMCS 10 and CMR 10 Font Inclusion

Tags: fonts

Can anyone please tell me simply how to use CMCS 10 and CMR10 font in LaTeX for specific text - sounds simple, but driving me nutty.

Comment: `cmr10` is the default of `book`, `report` or `article`. So please show us a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so illustrate your problem. Without the question is quite unclear.

Answer (score 6):

I do not know of a `cmcs10` font so I assume you mean `cmcsc10` (computer modern caps and small caps).

In which case

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Zzz \textsc{Zzz}
\end{document}
```

uses `cmr10` and `cmsc10`.

Comment: Or `cmss10`? Quit unclear.

Comment: I would prefer if the OP would clarify the question.

Comment: @Schweinebacke yes we'll see...